# how to search in an specific field in solr

Tags: asp.net-mvc, solr

hey i am using solr search in my mvc.net application. Now i am doing free search on it but i want this search on specific field.
i.e. - - -  i have various field like name, age, email, interest, profile
as i enter some text in search(free search) field i want that it searched only email field on indexed xml. how can i achieve it using free search.

Comment: How are you communicating with Solr? Are you using a specific client? I would recommend that you use solrnet (http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/). In that page, you have some documentation and also a very useful sample project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to search documents by a specific field, you can use the "fieldName:value" query format. eg. name:Manish

Comment: i know that thing but i want it on free search text box. I am using it on my mvc application and in free search i dont use tag name and all, so plz tell me that when i entered a text in my free text search box how can i upend a field name at run time

Comment: thanks dude.......... its done.. i use the following code to achieve.............                                                     new[] { new SolrQueryByField("fieldname", "" + parameter) || new SolrQueryByField("fieldname", "" + parameter)};